# Join two files linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to join two files but **they don't have the same number of lines.** I need to join them by the second column.

File1:

```
 11#San Noor#New York, US
 22#Maria Shiry#Dubai, UA
 55#John Smith#London, England
 66#Viki Sam#Roman, Italy
 81#Sara Moheeb#Montreal, Canada
```

File2:

```
 C1#Steve White#11
 C2#Hight Look#21
 E1#The Heaven is more#52
 I1#The Roma Seen#55
```

The output should be:

The output for **paired** lines should look like:

```
 San Noor#Sereve White
```

The output for **unpairable** lines should look like:

```
 Sara Moheeb#NA
```

**(The file3 after joining should contain 5 lines and look as followed.)**

```
  San Noor#Steve White
  Maria Shiry#Hight Look
  John Smith#The Heaven is more
  Viki Sam#The Roma Seen
  Sara Moheeb#NA
```

I have tried to join these two files using this command:

```
join -t '#' -j2 -e "NA" <(sort -t '#' -k2 File1) <(sort -t '#' -k2 File2) > File3
```

It says that both files are not sorted. Also, I need a way to fill in missing values after join.

Comment: Your files don't have any second column entries in common...

Comment: Show us what you expect the joined file should look like.  @Shawn is right.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to `paste` files instead of `join` (ach, those unix command names...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract relevant columns and paste them together.

```
paste -d '#' <(cut -d '#' -f2 file1) <(cut -d '#' -f2 file2)
```

Well, but this will fail for the `NA` case, when one file has less lines then the other. You could pipe it to something along `awk -v OFS='#' -F'#' { for (i=1;i<NF;++i) if (length($i) == 0) $i="NA"; }` to substitute empty fields for the string `NA`.

So I guess your method is a possible one, but you have nothing to "join" on the files. So join on an a imaginary column with line numbers:

```
join -t'#' -eNA -a1 -a2 -o1.2,2.2 <(cut -d'#' -f2 file1 | nl -w1 -s'#') <(cut -d'#' -f2 file2 | nl -w1 -s'#')
```

Comment: Can you explain to me this line: join -t'#' -eNA -a1 -a2 -o1.2,2.2 <(cut -d'#' -f2 file1 | nl -w1 -s'#') <(cut -d'#' -f2 file2 | nl -w1 -s'#'). This works

Comment: What exactly is in this line that you don't understand? https://explainshell.com/

Comment: "-a1 -a2 -o1.2,2.2"  and  "nl -w1 -s"

Comment: See [`man join`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) and [`man nl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl). `-a` also prints unpairable lines from file. `-o` specifies output format - I am interested in second column from first file and second column from second file. The `-w` is by default `6`, so by default `nl` adds leading spaces. So I use`-w1` so that numbers are glued to the left. `-s` set's number separator for `nl`. Test it out - `seq 5 | nl` vs `seq 5 | nl -w1 -s'#'`....